# How do we tap into hiding individual status bar items in our extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, statusbar

According to https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_36#_hide-individual-status-bar-items we can now enable users to turn status bar messages on/off, but it doesn't point to a particular API to handle that ourselves.

I have looked at https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/statusbar-sample but it doesn't seem to show a method of handling that.

Is there a good example somewhere we can refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried this myself, but going by the API docs, when you use [window.createStatusBarItem](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#window) you get back a [StatusBarItem](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#StatusBarItem), which has a "hide" method.  So calling that method seems like the first thing to try.

Comment: I forgot to update this question, but that's the route we took. We went with...

 `if (myStatusBarItem) {
  myStatusBarItem.hide();
 }`